# How do I assign a different cursor once clicked on a text box (Different from the one on hover) if the text box has a class attached to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, styling

I am not sure how I can change the cursor with a class attached to it in JavaScript. Currently, the code looks something similar to this...

```
/*HTML PART*/

<input onclick="Cursor1()" class="Box1" type="text" id="NumInput">

//JS

function Cursor1(){
    document.Box1.style.Cursor = 'text';
}
```

I was expecting this code to function and change the cursor when the textbox is clicked. But instead, it just keeps the normal one that was set as the normal in the CSS body tag.

I'd appreciate it if I could also get some help on switching the cursor back to what it was before the box was clicked when the user moves the cursor out of the textbox area.

Comment: When I hover over a text input or click on it in FF or Chromium browser, I see text cursor. I guess that your CSS has already a rule setting the default cursor for the input. Notice, that classes don't create properties to `document`, use ex. `document.getElementById` to get a reference to the input element.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
input:hover {
 cursor: cell;
}
```

when you hover over or click in input area, new cursor will appear, when hover out it will switch to default.
you can use custom cursors also with any image or icon you want to.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-cursor-property